# Matplotlib not depicting values on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm using Matplotlib in a Jupyter notebook to create some plot data for semiconductor devices I'm measuring. However, when I run inline commands, the generated plot doesn't have any markers with values on the Y axis (i.e. there are no values for Ig on the y axis, as shown in the plot).

This is my current plot:
[image: plot]

I've checked whether the rcParams I set for the plot have any influence on this (they don't seem to) as well as changing the figure size, removing tight layout, and DPI in case these were somehow compressing the values off the plot. I've also tried restarting the kernel and restarting my Jupyter session / checking for any Jupyter upgrades, but this also did not affect the plot. I tried reproducing the error in separate code as well and was not able to do so (strangely). I've included text of code I used to generate the plot, although I can't include the data used to generate it. . Any advice on things to try would be helpful!

```
def IdVg(devicedict, categorylist, W=20,line_labels=True): 
   # Get names of devices 
   labels = devicedict.keys() 
   IdVg_figure = plt.figure(figsize=(2.4, 2)) 
   plt_id_vg = IdVg_figure.add_subplot() 

   handles = [] 

   # For each device, grab its filepath/color and get the voltage/current data
   for label in labels: 
       filepath = devicedict[label][0]
       color = devicedict[label][1]
       (Vg, Vd, Id, Ig) = Import_IdVg_Vd(filepath)

    # Vd is measured across the same range twice; so take half the range for plotting purposes 
       Vg = Vg[:int(len(Vg)/2)]
       Id = Id[:int(len(Id)/2)]

       plt_id_vg.plot(Vg, Id*1e3/W, color = color, linewidth = 1, label ="{0} mV".format(np.squeeze(Vd)*1e3))

# Add line labels if desired 
    if line_labels:
       labelLines(plt_id_vg.get_lines(), zorder=5, xvals = (1, 1.6), fontsize = 'xx-small')

# Set legends based on categories defined by user 
   for item in categorylist: 
       lab = item[0]
       col = item[1]
       handles.append(mpatches.Patch(color=col, label=lab))


# Set plot parameters
   plt_id_vg.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
   plt_id_vg.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.2))
   plt_id_vg.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05))
   plt_id_vg.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
   plt_id_vg.set_xlim(left=0.4)
   plt_id_vg.set_xlabel("$V_{gs}$ (V)", fontweight = 'bold')
   plt_id_vg.set_ylabel("$I_{ds} (mA/\mu m)$", fontweight = 'bold')
   plt_id_vg.legend(handles = handles, prop={'size': 5}, framealpha = 0)
   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexK -- I'll switch the images to text!

Comment: Try comment the two lines `yaxis.set_minor_locator()` and `yaxis.set_major_locator()` and see if that brings back the ticks

Comment: Depending on the values of `Id` and `W`, `Id*1e3/W` will probably be in another range than `MultipleLocator(0.05)` indicates.

Comment: It was a MultipleLocator problem -- thanks @Redox @JohanC! if either of you want to post as an answer I'll mark it as correct